# Understanding this 8Mhz on-off keyed reception circuit

Tags: circuit-design, active-filter, passive-filter

[image]

This circuit takes an 8Mhz on-off keyed signal and down converts it to 128kHz double ended for an analog front end. "MIXER CLK" is 8.192kHz

One thing I don't understand is why the "Enable RX" turns on an npn transistor and pulls the receive antenna (Cap. PAD) through 100ohm to ground. Wouldn't this kill the weak 8Mhz signal? What does the C33 cap do? How does the pi network convert the signal from single-ended to 2 signals? What are these signals now? I have been asked to copy this signal chain but there is so much I don't understand about this circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable Rx has 2 cascaded inverting **(Q6/Q4)** NPN's so Hi input gives open circuit high output, not low **and also Q1 NPN/PNP to enable power for U7**

C33 shunts the RF on one side to make it a single ended input.

C31,32 makes a tank circuit and impedance/voltage divider ratio to keep the input impedance of the [SA612](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SA612A.pdf) from lowering the Q of the tank circuit.

The RFin =1.5k of the SA612.

470pF is around 50 ohms so the Q is around 30.

To get 128kHz, the mixer clk has to be 128kHz higher (or lower) than the 8MHz RF input or 8.128MHz

Comment: Tony - Thanks for the answer. I read the SA612 datasheet more thoroughly based on your answer. Is this circuit a superhet? Also, did you mean Enable Rx for Q6 or Q1? I meant why does Q6 pull the receive signal to ground.

Comment: Q6 turns On then Q4 turns Off from Rx En=1.  Then C31//L1 presents ~50 ohm reactive load and impedance transformer. yes Anything with an LO, mixer to IF BPF is a "superhet". Q1 uses NPN/PNP to go active high for Power enable to IF mixer IC

Comment: Is Enable Rx then active low? When it is 0 then Q4 turns on Vcc for the SA612 and Q6 is off and Q4 can amplify? Somehow thinking 1 is enabled stuck in my head and wouldn't let me figure this out.

Comment: Nope. Think of the common emitter as a saturated switch in these cases an inverter or normally open inverting switch.   Rxen=1 is positive logic and Q4 becomes the transmitter when RxEn=0 with the same tank circuit and 1.2k load impedance only when transmitting as inside the SA614 when receiving.

Comment: Isn't Q4 an amplifier? Like a pre-amp? Or is it a switch?

Comment: Q4 is a high gain amplifier. can you see how much?  Q1 turns on Vcc for SA612